# self is not available in swift project

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I am trying to run an image comparison in swift. However i am getting an error that states `Cannot use instance member 'featureprintObservationForImage' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`.
the error appears on the first of the `let` lines.

Why would self not already available within the ViewController?

```
import UIKit
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    
    func featureprintObservationForImage(atURL url: URL) -> VNFeaturePrintObservation? {
        let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(url: url, options: [:])
        let request = VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest()
        do {
          try requestHandler.perform([request])
          return request.results?.first as? VNFeaturePrintObservation
        } catch {
          print("Vision error: \(error)")
          return nil
        }
      }
    
    let apple1 = featureprintObservationForImage(atURL:Bundle.main.url(forResource:"apple1", withExtension: "jpg")!)
    let apple2 = featureprintObservationForImage(atURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource:"apple2", withExtension: "jpg")!)
    let pear = featureprintObservationForImage(atURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource:"pear", withExtension: "jpg")!)
    var distance = Float(0)
    try apple1!.computeDistance(&distance, to: apple2!)
    var distance2 = Float(0)
    try apple1!.computeDistance(&distance2, to: pear!)
    
}
```

Comment: You can't do imperative code like `try apple1!.computeDistance(&distance, to: apple2!)` at the top level of a class or struct like you're trying to do. That code has to go inside a function.

Comment: When an instance is created, the functions inside do not exist until all variables are initialised.

Comment: Great thanks, that sorted it. i understand now haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the code after the closing brace for your `featureprintObservationForImage` function is not inside any function or closure. You can't do that. (That code is not just variable decalrations. You have function calls, which is not legal outside of a function.)

You **can** create something called computed properties, where you provide a closure that gets invoked each time you read a value from the property.